# Select images with identical source to add unique class to each

Tags: jquery

I want to add the same class to the images whose sources are same. For example I have this

```
<img src="abc.png">
<img src="abc.png">
<img src="def.png">
<img src="def.png">
<img src="ghi.png">
```

and I want to acheive following

```
<img src="abc.png" class="g1">
<img src="abc.png" class="g1">
<img src="def.png" class="g2">
<img src="def.png" class="g2">
<img src="ghi.png" class="g3">
```

Comment: Based on your example, you also want to apply a class to those images that do not share a src with any other img elements, is that correct? So that if in your example all 5 were unique, the class would be `g1` through `g5`?

Comment: sorry if i didn't get you right but the class name is actually dynamic and it changes 1 degree per each set of identical images. for example g1 to g2 and all those images are contained in a div say myImages

Comment: So if abc.png also appears at the end of the list, it should get the same class as the first element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another way, Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var images = $("img") , number = 0 , imgLastSrc = null;
    images.each(function(){
        var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        if(imgSrc != imgLastSrc){         
            imgLastSrc = imgSrc;
            number++;
        }
        $(this).addClass("g" + number);
    });

});
```

**See** [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hallaji/J92uB/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the sources you are looking for, you can just use an attribute selector:

```
$("img[src='abc.png']").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("g1");
});

$("img[src='def.png']").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("g2");
});

$("img[src='ghi.png']").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("g3");
});
```

If your source is dynamic, try this:

```
var items=new Object();
var idx = 0;
$("img").each(function () {

    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    var newClass = "";
    if (items[src])
        newClass = items[src];
    else {
        idx++;
        newClass = "g" + idx;
        items[src] = newClass;
    }

    $(this).addClass(newClass);

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xX83X/

Comment: yeah you are correct but dynamic source is the problem.

Comment: @Azee I added a dynamic example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that's a bit round-a-bout, but clean:

```
//  get jquery object of img elements
var allImages = $('img[src]');

// filter out duplicates
allImages = $.unique(allImages);

// instantiate empty array to hold src attr values
var imageSrcs = [];


// loop through elements and push unique src values to imageSrcs   
allImages.each(function() {
  if ( $.inArray( $(this).attr('src'), imageSrcs ) == -1) {
    imageSrcs.push($(this).attr('src'));
  }
});

// loop through unique src attributes array and use in selector to apply .addClass     
$.each(imageSrcs, function(index, value) {
    $("img[src='" + value + "']").addClass("g" + index);
});
```

It could probably apply the class as it loops through the unique values, but this is more clear as it ensures the count is correct and is more fun because it uses two different jquery `each()` functions.

[Fiddle for testing.](http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/WEnBJ/)